# Add hyperlink onclick listener to JEditorPane

Tags: java, listener, jeditorpane

I'd like to add an hyperlink onclick listener to a simple web page displayed inside a JEditorPane. I have the following code but it is not working

```
  JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
    jep.setEditable(false);   
    String currenturl="http://www.newsite.com";
    try {
        jep.addHyperlinkListener(this);
      jep.setPage(currenturl);

    }catch (IOException e) {
      jep.setContentType("text/html");
      jep.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Before adding listener the JEditorPane should have EditorKit (content type "text/html" sets HTMLEditorKit which can provide logic to process URL clicks). Also the JEditorPane must not be editable.

so call

```
jep.setContentType("text/html");
jep.setEditable(false);
```

before adding the listener

UPDATE: if you wuld like to process links in editable JEditorPane check [this](http://java-sl.com/tip_links_in_editable.html)

Comment: Can I use it for jep.setPage() ?